# Drag/drop controls onto child Canvas without parent Canvas being notified

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a visual "designer" that will allow users to drag controls from a toolbox onto a design canvas. The excellent tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part) has helped me get a basic system up and going - I can drag controls from the toolbox, select and resize them etc. Amongst other things,the code uses a modified `Canvas` control, overriding the `OnDrop` method.

However, I'd like to give the user the option of defining "panels" within the design: effectively smaller Canvas's containing the toolbox controls - as an example:

[image]

So when the user drags the button onto Canvas_1, `OnDrop` fires and all is good. However, if the user creates Canvas_2, and then drags the button onto Canvas_2 - itself a child control of Canvas_1 - the parent `OnDrop` still fires and the button is added to Canvas_1.

I've tried setting the ZIndex of Canvas_2 to greater than Canvas_1, to no avail - the parent Canvas always gets the event. How can I ensure that Canvas_2 gets the `OnDrop` events for controls landing on it? Is there a different approach I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event [`DragDrop.DragEnter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dragenter(v=vs.110).aspx) uses a bubbling routing strategy, that means the event will travel upwards in the visual tree starting from the source element, giving a chance for all the elements along the route to handle the event.

When you drop something in the inner `Canvas`, it handles it, but doesn't stop the event propagation, so the parent element (the containing `Canvas`) will handle it again.

In the overriden `OnDrop` method you have a `DragEventArgs` parameter.
Set its `Handled` property to `true` if you want to prevent containing elements to handle the same event.

**Example**

I created a simple derived `Canvas` as well:

```
public class MyCanvas : Canvas
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StopDropPropagationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "StopDropPropagation", typeof (bool), typeof (MyCanvas), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

    public bool StopDropPropagation
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(StopDropPropagationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StopDropPropagationProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Children.Add(new TextBlock
        {
            Text = "Dropped here"
        });

        e.Handled = StopDropPropagation;
    }
}
```

In the view I've put two of these, one nested inside the other.

```
<local:MyCanvas AllowDrop="True" Background="DarkGray">
    <local:MyCanvas Width="300" Height="300" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="10" Background="BurlyWood" 
                    StopDropPropagation="True"></local:MyCanvas>
</local:MyCanvas>
```

The thing to note is that I added the new `DependencyProperty` called `StopDropPropagation` and set it to `true` in the inner `Canvas`. That will set the `Handled` to true.

So when I drop something in the inner `Canvas` the `TextBlock` will only be added in that element:

[image: drop demo]

Comment: Thank you, that's a big help.